# Getting event when new data can be read - chrome.socket.read API

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Trying to use TCP sockets using `chrome.socket` API on Chrome Version 25.0.1364.5 dev.

Looking at the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html) for the `chrome.socket.read` there doesn't seem to be a way to get a notification when new data is available to be read.

There is some [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/tcpserver/tcp-server.js) for a TCP server which polls the read command every 500ms but I think this would not be efficient / accurate

```
// Start polling for reads.
setInterval(this._periodicallyRead.bind(this, socketId), 500);
```

What's more confusing is that in the ['Network Communications' Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network.html) under section 'Receiving data', it is stated that a special handler can be passed as an `onEvent` option in `chrome.socket.create`

> The parameter is an object with one value 'onEvent' that is a function reference to the method that will be called when data is available on the port.

This onEvent parameter would be used like this

```
chrome.socket.create(
    'udp', '127.0.0.1', 1337, 
    { onEvent: handleDataEvent }, // <-- call this when new data is available
    createHandler
)
```

But this appears to apply only for UDP connections as I get the following error when I try to use it

```
Error: Invocation of form 
       socket.create(string, string, integer, object, function) 
       doesn't match definition 
       socket.create(string type, optional object options, function callback)

        at Object.normalizeArgumentsAndValidate (schemaUtils:119:11)
        at Object.<anonymous> (schema_generated_bindings:301:32)
        at chrome-extension://obljaojhdffbpcdfbeoiejegaodfoonp/background.js:11:15
        at chrome.Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:387:21)
        at chrome.Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:373:27)
        at dispatchArgs (event_bindings:249:22)
        at Object.app.runtime.onLaunched (app.runtime:116:7)
        at Object.chromeHidden.Event.dispatchEvent (event_bindings:255:35)
```

So the question is, can something like this be achieved with TCP Connections ? Instead of having to poll the `read` method every x milliseconds ?

**Update**

This is a workaround I am using until better documentation / event support exists.

```
function onReadHandler(readInfo) {
     // do things with data
     // ....

     // re register handler with callback itself
     chrome.socket.read(socketId,null,onReadHandler);         
}

chrome.socket.read(socketId,null,onReadHandler);
```

Comment: does `onEvent:`  did not work for `tcp` sockets?

Comment: it will throw an Error saying that it expects different type of parameters.. I have updated the question with the trace

Comment: The "Network Communications" page and the [actual API docs](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html) seem to be out of sync -- there's no mention of `onEvent` in the API docs. Also, the API talks about `callback` parameters, but none of the socket functions are specified to accept callbacks. The docs look to be a bit of mess right now.

Comment: I updated the question with a workaround in case anyone is interested

Comment: @lostsource - I'm curious about your workaround: does this ever result in empty reads? Or will the callback only be fired if Chrome has some non-empty buffer to give to the callback?

Comment: @apsillers yes I believe the callback is only fired on a non-empty buffer. Still not 100% sure about my solution, however I have tested since yesterday with thousands of reads and had no failures

Comment: I confirm it is only fired on non-empty buffers (contrary to what I assumed when I wrote the sample). See comments in my answer below.

Comment: I think that is not a workaround, that is the _correct way_ to use as it's exactly the same way you do that in `Boost::ASIO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For TCP connections, the callback passed to socket.read will only be executed when there is new data available. The [sample code mentioned](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/tcpserver/tcp-server.js#L255) was fixed to only use the callback instead of the setInterval.

The Network documentation is indeed outdated and we are working hard to update it. If you want to avoid the risk of outdated docs during these days of quickly changing APIs, you should always check the [API reference docs](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index.html) - those are generated directly from the code and don't need editorial work. If you are feeling "hacky" :-) you can also look directly at the Chromium [source code API definitions](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/) ([this one is for the socket API](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/socket.idl?view=markup))

Last, but not least, for [Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com) users, there is a [Sublime Chrome Apps and Extensions plugin](https://github.com/mangini/chrome-apis-sublime). It's not finished yet, but you can already get code completion, CSP validation and some boilerplates for bootstrapping. Install it through the Sublime [Package Manager](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).

Comment: thanks for the info & links.. I happen to be a Sublime Text user so that plugin will definitely be useful. One last question, is there anything fundamentally wrong with the code I've posted (onReadHandler) ? should I switch to the setInterval method

Comment: I was going to reiterate that the setInterval would be better for performance but then I decided to check it. Thanks to Chrome Dev Tools Timeline tab, I just found out that the method you used is actually better.  The socket.read method does not call the callback until new data is available, then the busy wait never happens. I will update the sample using your method, thanks! :-) (and will update the answer here too)

Comment: great, thanks for the re-assurance. I have just one doubt if the 're-registration' of the callback should happen after working on the data (as is now) or before  (first line in callback)

Comment: There is no difference, since your code is single threaded and the data received while you are handling the message will be saved in the read buffer anyway.

Comment: Thanks @mangini. What about for UDP sockets? Does the same principle apply, ie. the callback is only called when data is available to be read?